# Are there keyboard shortcuts to access the desktop menu in Gnome or how can I create them?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, desktop, gnome

I would like to access the desktop menus for Applications, System, etc. via my keyboard instead of my mouse.

Edit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> only lets me choose amongst the windows I have opened. There is no option to choose the desktop menus. Nothing happens with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>. (I've looked at various pages for gnome desktop shortcuts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default in my Gnome-under-Ubuntu installation:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> pops the Applications menu open (then the four arrow keys to navigate).
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> pops up the Run Application dialog.

And I've bound <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to open up a terminal.

Comment: You're welcome.  I was glad to find those keys, myself.  "*argh* not the mouse again!"  ;)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/2289.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts